# How to call a template function correctly?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I am new to template function and cannot figure this error. Hope you can help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/*
 * Print to the screen the content of a vector
 * Define function template in the header
 */
template <typename T> void print_vector(T& v) {
    for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> field;
    field.resize(12, 1);

    /*
    for( std::vector<int>::const_iterator i = field.begin(); i != field.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    */

    print_vector(field);
}
```

My code failed to compile with a very long error message that I can't even insert here.

```
error: conversion from ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >}’ requested
utility.h:21:59: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘i != (& v)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<int, std::allocator<int> >()’
utility.h:21:59: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.7/./bits/c++allocator.h:34:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/allocator.h:48,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/istream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/fstream:40,
                 from utility.h:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:134:5: note: template<class _Tp> bool __gnu_cxx::operator!=(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:134:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
utility.h:21:59: note:   ‘std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >::const_iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > > >}’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>’
```

Comment: In the function signature, you should have `std::vector<T> &` as the parameter type, instead of `T &`.

Comment: For what it’s worth, C++ doesn’t have template functions, it has “function templates”. This is actually a very relevant difference. In C++, you have templates *for* functions, i.e. a template from which the compiler creates functions – not functions which are templates.

Answer (score 4):

When you call

```
std::vector<int> field;
...
print_vector(field);
```

the `T` in `print_vector`<sup>1</sup> is the type of `field`, i.e., `std::vector<int>`. Therefore the `typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator` in

```
for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator i = v.begin();
```

is a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >::const_iterator`, to which `v.begin()` (itself being a `std::vector<int>::iterator`) is not convertible. Use

```
for(typename T::const_iterator i = v.begin();
```

instead.

<sup>1</sup> That is to say: in the function that's made from the function template `print_vector` for this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your function:

```
template <typename T> 
void print_vector(T& v) {
    for(typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

`T` is deduced as `std::vector<int>`, so you're trying to convert a `std::vector<int>::iterator` (the result of `v.begin()`) into a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>::const_iterator` (the type of `i`), which is not a valid conversion.

Instead, just make a more specialized template function:

```
 template <typename T>  
 void print_vector(std::vector<T>& v) {
    // as before
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You called the function properly. But then you confused the template-argument (type of the container) with the containers element-type.

Anyway, there's no reason for it not being `const`.

Thus, it should look like this instead:

```
template <typename T> void print_vector(const T& v) {
    for(typename T::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

Or using the standard-library and lambdas:

```
template <typename T> void print_vector(const T& v) {
    using std::begin; // Using ADL for begin and end to support raw arrays
    using std::end;
    std::for_each(begin(v), end(v), [](auto&& x){std::cout<<*i<<' ';});
}
```

Or using `auto` and range-for-loops (my favorite):

```
template <typename T> void print_vector(const T& v) {
    for(auto&& i : v)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

Or using C++1z (projected for 2017):

```
void print_vector(const auto& v) {
    for(auto&& i : v)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: The last one (`for(i : v)`) was rejected at the last committee meeting.

Comment: @T.C.: Why did they reject it? Do you know?

Comment: I think it's due to concerns that it would declare (and potentially shadow) something without looking like a declaration. After `int i = 0; vector<int> v{1}; for(i : v);`, `i` is still 0.

Answer (score 0):

Either replace `std::vector<T>::const_iterator i` with simply `T::const_iterator i` if you want to pass it any iterable, or specialize it appropriately with `void print_vector(std::vector<T>& v)` if you wish for it to only work against vectors of any types.

If you run a substitution as you have it now you will see you are giving a vector to something creating a vector out of the type, hence getting a vector of vector.

Also GCC 4.8 and 4.9 have improved messages and add a more precise error caret.
If you can't move compiler, which is understandable, then you can always feed small snippets like that to an online one like ideone.com. The error would most likely have been a lot more concise and readable in 4.8.

Oh, and if you have access to C++11 features (I don't remember what made it in 4.7) you can auto those type declarations AND use something like cbegin() instead of begin to get the type resolution to pick a const_iterator instead of a normal one. If you're learning about templates, and have no work environment constraints, I would strongly recommend a move to C++11 and a more recent GCC, it will make easing in a lot easier.